# What is the equation that gives $a$ and $b$ of the elliptical polarization formed by two interfering linearly polarized waves?

Tags: optics, waves, visible-light, interference, polarization

Two linearly polarized light waves have amplitudes $A1$ and $A2$, the same wavelength, a phase difference of $p$, and an angle difference of $\theta$.

When two linearly polarized light waves with different phases interfere, they create an elliptical polarization pattern.

The semi-major axis of an ellipse is a, and the semi-minor axis is b.

Given the properties of the two light waves, how can I calculate a and b of the elliptical polarization?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. It took a while for me to work it out, but here are the equations: (a is not always major and b is not always minor, but they are two different axis)

```
a = √((a1 sin(p) + a2 sin(θ) sin(p))^2 + (a2 cos(θ) sin(p))^2)
b = √((a1 sin(p + π/2) + a2 sin(θ) sin(p + π/2))^2 + (a2 cos(θ) sin(p + π/2))^2)
```

(all variables are real numbers, not vectors)

(It is hard to explain, it took me a while to figure it out)

The sin of a phase of a wave is equal to the wave's "value" at that point. Basically the **output of the sin function**. As x gets greater, the wave value changes. Basically, I do not know why, but the sin of the phase difference is equal to the wave value where one of the semi-axis is **(what I mean by that is that at the point on the wave, p, and the point on the other wave, p, when they interfere like all other points do, these ones create one of the semi-axis)**. You may notice that it uses a^2 + b^2 = c^2 to get the distance (**i.e. a or b from the center of polarization**). We are calculating distance (a^2 + b^2 = c^2), so we need to have two perpendicular directions (i.e. x and y), so I broke it up into two parts (the parts that get squared). We can assume that one wave is always facing straight up in the y direction, since we are using angle difference instead of two different angles. That wave is `a1 sin(p)`. It gets the wave value at the position where one of the semi-axis is and multiplies it by the amplitude. Since the second wave is at a tilt, it has a bit of y and a bit of x.  We get the y part by getting the sin of θ (like in a right triangle), the wave value at the semi-axis (sin(p)), and multiply them all with the amlpitude. That is in the y direction. Now the x direction is the same, but we get the x direction of the tilted wave by cos of θ instead of sin (again like a right triangle). We do the same thing as before (wave value at semi-axis, and amplitude). Then we square both, add them, and square root the sum. This gets one of the semi-axis.

The second semi-axis is the exact same as the first one, except we add π/2 to the phase difference. When we add π/2, it gets the other semi-axis (this is because there is 2π in a full elliptical cycle and there are 4 semi-axis. 2 major-semi-axis and 2 minor-semi-axis 2π/4 = π/2). Everything else in that equation is the exact same.